# Why is it better to use DDP to talk to Meteor server instead of using JSON?

Tags: ios, json, meteor, ddp

I am interested in writing iOS apps, and other client apps that need to communicate with my Meteor server to update and get information.

Using this collection API https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi

I can perform CRUD operations on meteor collections using restful http methods and JSON from the iOS app.

But I read that it is preferred to use DDP to talk to the Meteor server. Which means I would have to get some iOS DDP communication tool. JSON parsing and making http requests are built into xcode. Why use DDP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are totally different things.

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a **data transfer format** based on the JS object syntax. It's the *notation/syntax* how the data is written. Think of it as a car on the road, among different kinds of vehicles.

[DDP](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md) is a **messaging protocol**. It's *how the data is structured and passed* around for multiple systems to understand. Think of DDP as the traffic system.

DDP could have been written in any other format (like XML, binary etc.) and passed through a different protocol (HTTP, FTP etc.) but the authors chose JSON on websockets.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so why use DDP to communicate with meteor server vs just making a request and getting and sending json data?

Comment: @nearpoint Please read the DDP protocol for more details. And yes, DDP *is* for getting and sending data.